# Printing Characters after a Colon

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, cut

How do I print anything after the colon?

Input:

```
color:white,name:green
```

so I would like to print anything after `:`

Output:

```
white,green
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple **`sed`** approach (while your input is pretty simple):

```
sed 's/[^,:]*://g' file
```

The output:

```
white,green
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `grep`:

#### GNU grep

```
grep -oP '(?<=:)\w+'
```

#### Portable grep

```
grep -o ':[a-z]\+' | tr -d :
```

#### Output in both cases

```
white
green
```

#### Note about output

If you want the output as a comma-separated list, pipe to `paste`, e.g.:

```
grep -o ':[a-z]\+' | tr -d : | paste -sd, -
```

Output:

```
white,green
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk -F':' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: The ***statement*** of the question is vague,  but if you look at the sample data, you’ll see that this answer is wrong.